# Import ordering of js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

A library is imported on a jsp file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mylibrary.js"></script>
```

Code is then executed further in the .jsp which requires this library :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//various calls take place to myLibrary.js
<script>
```

I want to extract the javascript functions/function calls into an external .js file. So replace :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//various calls take place to myLibrary.js
<script>
```

with :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="newfile.js"></script>
```

Where 'newfile.js' contains the functions/function calls.

Does this mean I will need to import "mylibrary.js" within "newfile.js" ?

What is the import ordering of javascript/jquery ?

Comment: There are no imports in javascript. You just can (and do) export to the global scope, and other scripts can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean I will need to import "mylibrary.js" within "newfile.js" ?

No. There is no difference between an inline script and a remote one as far as execution order and scope is concerned.

> What is the import ordering of javascript/jquery ?

If a script element containing (or sourcing) a function declaration hasn't been parsed before you try to call the function, there will be an error.

If you want to call a function defined by jQuery, then you must place the `<script>` that loads jQuery before the `<script>` that loads code which makes the call to the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several javaScript files in your webpage and you want to make sure that everything is loaded, at the point you want to use it, you can either use:

- `$(document).ready()` (or an equivalent) 
  or
- you can concatenate the files for your webpage in the correct order prior to delivery.

Comment: would the `$(document).ready()` option require JQuery or compatible?

Comment: the function `ready()` is provided by jQuery, so: yes, you need jQuery for that.